# ASP.NET MVC Pass multiple optional parameters field=value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to a GET method

```
[Route("v1/v2/v3/?{param}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent(string param)
```

from current request that can look like:

```
https://localhost:44363/v1/v2/v3/?isFormatSimple=true
```

OR

```
https://localhost:44363/v1/v2/v3/?vers=v1.2.7&allow=true
```

For the first I'll have to get the value from `isFormatSimple` and for the second, `v1.2.7` and `true`.

But I don't know how can I get those values. Can I check if I have a specific parameter inside a single method?
Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: As I understand, you want to write an endpoint for your WEB application that can be called on route `https://localhost:44363/v1/v2/v3` with a **HTTP GET** method, and you want to pass **multiple (string) parameters** to it . Is it correct?

Comment: @turanszkik yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to simply make overloads of your API controller method (1 overload per set of parameters). Then when you send it your request, it will determine which overload matches the format of your request and use that one.
(I've used this at work, and this article shows its use as well: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-get-method-aspnet-core-mvc)
Example Code:

```
[HttpGet ("v1/v2/v3/")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent([FromQuery] bool isFormatSimple)
{ 
  // your method
}

[HttpGet ("v1/v2/v3/")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent([FromQuery] string version, [FromQuery] bool allow)
{ 
  // your method
}
```

The next simplest option is to actually put the parameters into your route, instead of into your query, and still use overloads:
Code:

```
[HttpGet ("v1/v2/v3/{isFormatSimple:bool}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent([FromRoute] bool isFormatSimple)
{ 
  // your method
}

[HttpGet ("v1/v2/v3/{version}&{allow:bool}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent([FromRoute] string version, [FromRoute] bool allow)
{ 
  // your method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
[Route("{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{optionalParam?}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent(string v1, string v2, string v3, string optionalParam)
```

and any other parameters in your action's signature will be considered as query string. Like this:

```
[Route("{v1}/{optionalParam?}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent(string v1, string optionalParam, string queryString)
```

your request would look like this:

```
https://localhost:44363/v1/optionalParam?queryString=HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see two ways of calling a **HTTP GET** endpont and passing multiple parameters to it

First its a basic way, with conventional parametering that is wide used on the web:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ParamsInBasicUrlFormat")]
    public async Task<string> ParamsInBasicUrlFormat(string v1, string v2, string v3)
    {
        return $"{v1};{v2};{v3}";
    }
```

Which you can call with the following format: `http://localhost:61652/ParamsInBasicUrlFormat?v1=first param&v2=second param&v3=third param`

Second if you want to pass parameters in the URL like it would be the part of the path:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ParamsInOtherUrlFormat/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}")]
    public async Task<string> ParamsInOtherUrlFormat(string v1, string v2, string v3)
    {
        return $"{v1};{v2};{v3}";
    }
```

Which you can call with the following format: `http://localhost:61652/ParamsInOtherUrlFormat/first/second/third`

The basic idea if you put `{something}` in the **Route attribute** you have to put it in the input of the method also. Without the input specification in the route attribute, the application expect the attributes in the way like the first example shows.